# Употребления глагола "корючится" для статичных объектов

Tags: значение-слов

Может ли слово "корючится" заменить глагол "торчит" во фразе вроде "из стены корючится проволока"?
Мне представляется, что может. Однако просмотренные мной словари в большей степени наводят на мысль, что "корючиться" означает движение, типа "извиваться", "загибаться". Но всё же и "извивается" и "загибается" допустимо применить к статичным объектам для описания их формы. Стало быть, "корючится" тоже можно?

Comment: Где есть значение *извиваться?*

Comment: Да, нигде нет. Перепутал